# What is the fastest way to determine n^m = m^n if m != n?

Tags: c, c++14, number-theory

It's one of the questions from the practice section in hackerearth. We need to determine whether m^n = n^m. It is trivial when n = m, so we focus on m != n.

```
1 <= m, n <= 10^10000
```

What I have tried is

```
n^m = m^n  implies
m*log(n) = n*log(m)
```

But the problem is how to take log of such a huge number? Is there an alternative way of checking equality?

Comment: 2^3=8,3^2=9 therefore n^m cannot be equal to m^n. not really a programming question though

Comment: it is not that easy. check the range of values n, m can take.

Comment: Are these integers?

Comment: Which language is this, C or C++?

Comment: Yes. but definitely you have to store these in strings.

Comment: C or C++, any of these will work.

Comment: @dangee1705, could please also prove Fermat's last theorem? Because 2^4 = 4^2.

Comment: If they are integers the only solutions are: `n==m` and `n==2 && m==4` and `n==4 && m==2`

Comment: [Finding Integer Solutions to a^b = b^a](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/67256.html), [If a and b are distinct integers and a^b = b^a, how many](https://gmatclub.com/forum/if-a-and-b-are-distinct-integers-and-a-b-b-a-how-many-103461.html)

Comment: @chelsea it is that easy because to disprove n^m=m^n you only need one case where it is not true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do some math to determine how to program for solutions:

It is easy to see that neither **n** nor **m** can equal 1 as they must be different and cannot be null. Let's look for solutions where **1 < n < m**.

As you correctly stated, **n<sup>m</sup> = m<sup>n</sup>** implies **m.log(n) = n.log(m)**

hence we are looking for solutions to **m / log(m) = n / log(n)** and **1 < n < m**.

We can study the function **f(x) = x / log(x)** for **x > 1**:

Its derivative is **f'(x) = (log(x) - 1) / log(x)<sup>2</sup>**

The derivative has a single zero at **x = e**, **f(x)** is strictly decreasing between **x = 1** and **x = e** and strictly increasing from **x = e** all the way to infinity.

Any 2 distinct numbers **n** and **m** such that **f(n) = f(m), n < m** must be such that **1 < n < e** and **m > e**

The only possible integer value for **n** is 2 and it happens to be a solution with the corresponding value of **m** as 4, there is no other integer in the interval 1 to e.

Hence the only solutions are n=2, m=4 and n=4, m=2

Here is a C program to output all possible results:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("2 4\n");
    printf("4 2\n");
    return 0;
}
```